# Weird Firefox Ajax Post error, on Chrome works fine, Opera fails too

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, firefox, post

I'm posting two variables to one php file, but i am getting this this error on firefox..

Timestamp: 12/15/2012 06:19:30 PM
Error: NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: Unexpected error
Source File: localhost/Algo
Line: 415

the code works on Chrome but fails too in Opera

the line 415 is the first line of the next code

```
var IDsData = new FormData($('#formulario')[0]);
    IDsData.append("IDsValidar", $('#gene_ids_area').val());
    IDsData.append("Organismo", $('#organism_box :selected').val());

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "check_ids.php",
        data: IDsData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        async: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data == "") {
            error = 0;
        } else {
            error = 1;
            error_msg += "The identifiers: " + data + "are not vaid for the organism selected.\n";

        }
    });
```

my php file is, and is content is here
It parses a file, to validate some Ids

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["IDsValidar"])) {
    $ids = $_POST["IDsValidar"];
}

if (isset($_POST["Organismo"])) {
    $organismo = $_POST["Organismo"];
}

$auxiliar = explode("\n",$ids);

foreach($auxiliar as $id)
{
$id = trim($id);
$fp = fopen("gene_names/$organismo.csv", 'r');
$paso_test = 0;
while($line = fgets($fp))
{   
        $line=trim($line);
    list($ID,$name)=explode(",",$line);
    if($id == $ID)
    {   
        $paso_test = 1;
    }
    if($id == $name)
    {
        $paso_test = 1;
    }
}   
if($paso_test == 0)
{   
    echo "$id\n";
}   
fclose($fp);    
}


?>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: [Check this for FormData](http://caniuse.com/#search=FormData) and your browser version.

Comment: it must work on my firefox and opera versions

Answer (score 0):

Change...

```
$('#formulario')[0]
```

to...

```
$('#formulario').get(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the paths of the files you require?
as Google Chrome automatically finds files and images, while Firefox and Opera don't.

I have had this problem with loading images from folders which Chrome could find and Firefox couldn't. solved this by creating a static path from root. www/folder/ajax/ajax.php

Answer (score 0):

Problem with `processData: false` - Firefox for some reason has a problem with that option.

You can temporarily solve it but setting `processData: true`, or possibly `data: JSON.stringify(data)`